# Template class generate errors in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

This program is not compiling. What's the problem?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

template<class T>class Data{
    string header;
    T data;
public:
    Data(string h, T d){header = h, data = d;}
    void WriteData()
    {
        cout<<header<<": "<<data<<endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Data<int> idata("Roll", 100);

    Data<string>sdata("Name","Jakir");

    idata.WriteData();
    sdata.WriteData();
    return 0;
}
```

Showing the following errors.

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>             c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679): could be 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<>(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)'
>            with
>            [
>                 _Elem=char,
>                 _Traits=std::char_traits
>             ]
>
> while trying to match the argument list '(std::ostream, std::string)'
>             .....\maptest\mapt\mapt\mapt.cpp(16) : while compiling class template member function 'void Data::WriteData(void)'
>             with
>             [
>                 T=int
>             ]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you forgot to:

```
 #include <string>
```

You cannot count on transitive inclusion of all the necessary header files because some other header like `<iostream>` may `#include` them.

If you are using `std::string`s, you should be `#include`ing the appropriate header (`<string>`) explicitly.

Overloads of `operator <<` which accept an `std::string` are probably declared/defined in a header which is *not* `#include`d by `<iostream>`.

Besides, avoid having `using` directives at global namespace scope such as this:

```
using namespace std;
```

They can easily lead to name clashes and it is normally regarded as a bad programming practice.

Comment: Oh my god. What a mistake I've made. Thanks a lot. It spoiled my 2 hours. thanks again.

Comment: @JakirHossain: We've all been there ;) Good luck with your project

Answer (score 2):

T_char is incorrect type as argv should have a type for example char*

Correct source code is

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template<class T>class Data{
    string header;
    T data;
public:
    Data(string h, T d){header = h, data = d;}
    void WriteData()
    {
        cout<<header<<": "<<data<<endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Data<int> idata("Roll", 100);

    Data<string>sdata("Name","Jakir");

    idata.WriteData();
    sdata.WriteData();
    return 0;
}
```